# Remove part of string but getting the deleted part as result

Tags: javascript

So, quick question (searched a lot in Google, but only found the answer which produces same response as below):

code:

```
var teste = '10/12/2017';
console.log(teste); //returns 10/12/2017
var teste_cut = teste.substr(6,2);
console.log(teste_cut); //returns only 20
```

What I want is `10/12/17`. I can't change how the string is created, so I need to change it after getting said string. Does a method for doing this exist, or should I work around with other functions? I'm feeling stupid right now, since it seens to be a fairly obvious answer, but I guess we all get our stupid moments :P

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: You can't just use `teste.substr(0,6) + teste.substr(8)`?

Answer (score 2):

One method to achieve this would be to cut the start and end portions of the string then join them back together, something like this:

```js
var teste = bookend('10/12/2017', 6, 7);
console.log(teste);

function bookend(str, start, end) {
  return str.substr(0, start) + str.substr(end + 1);
}
```

An alternative would be to use a regular expression to match the parts of the date you want to keep and then join them back together:

```js
var teste = '10/12/2017'.replace(/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/)(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1$3');
console.log(teste);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rebuild a new `string` without the parts you don't want using multiple `substr` :

```js
var test = '10/12/2017';
console.log(test);
var test_cut = test.substr(0,6)+test.substr(8,test.length);
console.log(test_cut)
```

Comment: thanks! Never thinked about chaining substr...

I got it working with a really ugly way of splitting the string, editing the last item and them rejoining the result. It worked, but your method is way nicer :D

PS: to all the others talking about the date method, I can't use that (the date I need to edit I receive in an Json object after a AJAX call), Should have said that. My bad...

Answer (score 1):

Simple regular expression with replace. match 4 numbers, keep the last two.

```
var t = '10/12/2017';
console.log(t.replace(/\d{2}(\d{2})$/, '$1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var teste = '10/12/2017'.replace(/(?=....$)../, '');
console.log(teste);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way would be to deal with Date object instead, it will ensure that you get right year always.

```
var newDate = new Date(teste);
console.log(((newDate.getFullYear()).toString()).substr(2,2));
```

Comment: Shouldn't `newYear` on line 2 be `newDate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom function as -

```js
function formatDate(d)
{
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    
    year = year.toString().substr(2,2);
    
    month = month + 1;

    month = month + "";

    if (month.length == 1)
    {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    day = day + "";

    if (day.length == 1)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}

var d = new Date('10/12/2017');
console.log(formatDate(d));
```